# Error: 'multiclass.roc.default' is not an exported object from 'namespace:pROC'

Tags: mlr

I'm using mlr R package (v2.3), trying to use multiclass auc as one of the measures when using CV in a 3-class classification problem. But, I'm getting the following error:

Error: 'multiclass.roc.default' is not an exported object from 'namespace:pROC'

I believe I have all the dependencies installed already (and don't believe that is the actual issue). The error is produced when trying to run the 'resample' function, as follows:

```
tsk <- makeClassifTask(data = dat, target = "best.model")
lrn <- makeLearner("classif.rpart", predict.type = "prob")
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters=10)
r <- resample(learner = lrn, task = tsk, resampling = rdesc, show.info = T, measures = list(acc, multiclass.auc))
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You haven't shown us your data, but when I run this with `iris` (first line `tsk <- makeClassifTask(data = iris, target = "Species")`) it works fine for me. Have you tried updating the `pROC` package?

Comment: Thanks. Am getting the same error even when using `iris`. I'm running the latest version of `pROC` but `mlr` is the 2.3.

Comment: Works fine for me with the latest version of mlr (2.4). Have you tried upgrading?

Comment: Yep. It works with the latest. I was trying to avoid upgrading as I'm using mlr heavily and wanted to be sure my package remained stable. Anyway, problem solved. thanks.

Comment: The release version is usually quite stable :)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with the latest version of mlr (2.4).